# Why is writing to a file faster than appending a string?

Tags: c#, string, streamwriter

Given that RAM is much faster than a hard drive, I was surprised by the code below.

I was trying to split a CSV files based on the value of one column, and write each line with different values in that cell to different files.

I was trying:

```
List<string> protocolTypes = new List<string>();
List<string> splitByProtocol = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in lineSplit)
{
    string protocol = getProtocol();
    index = protocolTypes.IndexOf(protocol);
    splitByProtocol[index] = splitByProtocol[index] + s + "\n";
}
```

Which took ages, but changing it to a stream writer was much faster:

```
List<string> protocolTypes = new List<string>();
List<StreamWriter> splitByProtocol = new List<StreamWriter>();
foreach (string s in lineSplit)
{
    string protocol = getProtocol();
    index = protocolTypes.IndexOf(protocol);
    splitByProtocol[index].WriteLine(s);
}
```

Why is writing to disk so much faster than appending strings together in memory? I know adding to a string requires copying the whole string to a new memory location, but appending a string was orders of magnitude slower than writing to disk which seems counter intuitive.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the real code because you are not adding items to the list(s).

Comment: I cut it down, there is code where if a new protocol is found it will create a new list item.

Comment: Every `+` operation creates a new string (which requires allocating memory). Try a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: The code as you´ve shown will propbably return an `IndexOutOfBoundException`, because `splitByProtocol` does not contain any elements and therefor `splitByProtocol[index]` will throw an exception.

Comment: [Read up on the basic of string concatenation](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Comment: @MikeS159: apart from the possible `IndexOutOfBoundException`, this simple string concatenation will not cause any noticeable perfiormance issues. How have you measured it at all? I guess that most work is done in `getProtocol`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sounds like you've not done much work in string manipulation if you think simple string concatenation will not cause performance issues.  It's an O(n^2) operation in both time and space.

Comment: @Servy, I did not know that string concatenation was O(n^2). One of the strings was probably getting very large, which was probably causing the slowdown.

Comment: @Servy: i wouldn't use string concatenation if this would be time critical or i need to do it with millions of strings. My point was that i'm pretty sure that OP hasn't measured correctly and also is comparing apples and oranges(f.e. not flushing a `StreamWriter`). Using a `List<StreamWriter>` seems to be weird too

Comment: If OP needs to write them to the files anyway, then why storing them somewhere else at all? Then the `StreamWriter` approach is clearly better because it doesn't need to waste memory(you could set `AutoFlush` to `true`). If it doesn't need to be written to a file there is no reason to do it, so why comparing it? Instead of concatenating every line he could also use a `List<List<string>>`, so one list for every "file".

Comment: @TimSchmelter It doesn't take millions of strings.  A few thousand of even fairly small strings is likely going to be slower than writing to a file, assuming it's sensibly buffered (which it would be in the code shown).  It's *entirely* plausible that the OP doesn't just have a measurement problem.  If he's got an entire files worth of strings it's quite likely that he has enough for it to not perform well.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I was just thinking that. While StringBuilder is faster (writing one large buffer at the end rather than lots of disk seeks each loop); it would use more memory. This isn't a problem on my computer, but for large CSV files on a computer without much RAM writing straight to disk would reduced RAM use significantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the strings become huge (many MB) then copying them definitely becomes time-consuming.

However the biggest hit may be caused by the many old strings that are no longer needed, sitting as garbage on the heap, waiting to be collected. So the garbage collector will kick in, possibly even many times, pausing your program every time.

For strings constructed in a loop like this, always consider using `StringBuilder` instead. To match your example code:

```
List<StringBuilder> splitByProtocol = new List<StringBuilder>();
foreach (string s in lineSplit)
{
    string protocol = getProtocol();
    index = protocolTypes.IndexOf(protocol);
    splitByProtocol[index].AppendLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First it allocates (a lot) of memory for the new string. Then it copyies over the existing string, and the part that is appended, byte for byte. This takes quite a few cycles, and for every loop the string gets longer so the overall operation time is exponential to the number of loops.

Also garbage collection of the Gen1 will mean that the latest string is copied to Gen2 (so copied again). That will fill up with a bunch of these old strings etc, so we get to Gen2. This approach creates quite some overhead on the GC.

For the disk it's only writing to the stream, so it is first in memory (fast) then disk cache (fast) until it is finally written to disk (slow, but that part is buffered so it'll look very fast). 
Also it is done only once so performance is pretty much linear with the number of loops.

BTW you might want to look into StringBuilder, that will probably be even faster.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your measurements are okay.

If still, the `StreamWriter` uses a buffer to write to, you append a string which will create a string every time again, which in the end will have excessive memory allocations, while the stream writer is still caching. Note that you aren't flushing, which means that the file is not written until flushed (which isn't forced by your code) and thus could mean you are just storing to a much more efficient memory storage than your string appending does. And even if it gets flushed, it does it at once. With a fast disk you end up faster than overly expensive string concatenation.

If you would use a `StringBuilder` for your first code, you will see your execution time will drop significantly. Then you will see the true difference in performance, and I am sure you will see `StringBuilder` is faster.

Comment: The buffer will flush itself automatically when it fills, so he's not *never* writing to the file.

Comment: Agreed, clarified @Servy

Comment: I had forgotten about `StringBuilder`, I will try it with that in future.